# C# How to use regex to find all ints in a big string

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to figure out how regex works. It has always been a mystery to me as I have had no need to ever use it as a game programmer.
An example would really help me.

Say I have this string.

```
[{"a":{"e":{"e":161,"a":"blue","d":{"e":-14,"a":"red","d":{"c":"yellow","a":[-35,0],"b":"orange","d":
```

I'd like to get all the ints from it, so the desired output would be an array of ints like this

```
{161,-14,-35,0}
```

ps. Why do I want to know this if I have never had a use for regex? Cus I'm doing this for fun. And this seems like a good oppertunity to learn about it.
http://adventofcode.com/

Comment: You might want to parse your string as JSON before extracting your ints from it. Otherwise, you'd inadvertently also extract ints embedded within key or value strings, such as the `-1` in `{"e-1b":"blue"}`.

Comment: I know that string looks like a json, but thats irrelevant

Comment: Well, `[-+]\d+` doesn't tell you much about regex. If you're really looking for C# regex usage functions/examples, check the `Regex` and methods in the MS docs, as there are many ways to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "[{\"a\":{\"e\":{\"e\":161,\"a\":\"blue\",\"d\":{\"e\":-14,\"a\":\"red\",\"d\":{\"c\":\"yellow\",\"a\":[-35,0],\"b\":\"orange\",\"d\":";
            string pattern = @"[-+]?\d+";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                output.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));
            }
            int sum = output.Sum();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: If you are learning regex see this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx